# Why is PrestaShop redirrecting to a random product when selecting variations from front-end?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules, prestashop-themes

I have an online shop in development, all went well until I decided to do SEO on the shop. After this, if I chose a product variation from front-end it just redirects me to a random product.

[image]
This picture describes the first state. The default product load.

[image]
This picture describes what is happening after you select a variation. As you can see the product name stays the same, but the link indicates that a totally different product is displayed.

If I have the debug mode enabled  when selecting a variation it throws "An error occurred while processing your request" and in the request file I can see that besides some errors (Deprecated: array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists()) it shows the request for a different product.

I can't understand why this is happening, so I am in dying need of your help.

Comment: What is your PHP version and what is your Prestashop version?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the entire index? Shop Parameters->Search

Comment: The PHP version is 7.4 and yes, I've tried that but I still get the same behavior.

Comment: UPDATE: I've changed it to 7.2 but I still get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this. Apparently or appeared because I was using the duplicate function for uploading products. I don't know why but on some products it makes this behavior.

I've spent over 12 hours to find a explanation for this and I was unable to find one. The PrestaShop forum straight up banned me for posting this topic.

My advice is to **NOT USE PRESTASHOP** it's and old sistem and full of bugs, the support is expensive and I get the impression that even they don't understand their system.

If you find yourself in this situation, know this. Don't duplicate and upload products using "add new" function.

And I can't state this enough, do yourself a favour and don't use Presta, with all the expenses the time to invest and what the product looks like at the end of the road, is just a waste of time. Even after you finish is guaranteed to break in 1-2 years, any updates will break your store and you will need to invest even more more to fix it. It's an old, slow and buggy CMS. It's days are numbered.

Thanks a lot for help.
Best regards, Daniel.

Comment: "do yourself a favour and don't use Presta" - Some of us do not have a choice in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way Prestashop 1.7 works :

First time a customer lands in a multi-variation page, the default attribute will be loaded,
URL will show only the ID product.

Once you choose an attribute , an AJAX call will refresh the page
with the current attribute and URL will change with id_product-id_product_attribute value.

Not sure what you mean by "random product" as in both of your examples I see an attribute
being selected.

Anyway there are several (paid) modules to change this behaviour in a better SEO perspective,
this is definitely one of the most famous :

https://addons.prestashop.com/en/url-redirects/16633-pretty-urls-seo-friendly-url-remove-ids-numbers.html

EDIT: Just noticed that the ID product is different in the two screenshot, this could be related to some DB issues with attribute too, you should check if you have some not coherent values between id_product and id_product_attribute(s)

Comment: I've checked, everything seems quite fine, there are no duplicate id's or even values. But I've found a loop.

The loop goes like this product > select variation > gives the wrong url but the initial product name stays the same > reload page (now it fully loads the wrong url) > select variation > gives the wrong url again > reload page (again fully loads the wrong url). Repeat this about 4-5 times and when you finally land on the original requested product, on variation change it displays "An error occurred while processing your request".

This is simply over my head, why such a behavior?